# How to inspect windows application using Appium

Tags: appium, appium-desktop, winappdriver

Is it possible to inspect a Windows application using Appium?
If yes can someone show me what "Desired Capability" shall be set to launch for example notepad?

What I have done is:

- Installed/Started Appium
- Launched server on 0.0.0.0:4723
- Clicked on start inspector
- Provided following capabilities:

  {
    "platformName": "Windows",
    "deviceName": "WindowsPC",
    "app": "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
  }

What i got back is the following log:

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe","deviceName":"WindowsPC","platformName":"Windows","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe","deviceName":"WindowsPC","platformName":"Windows","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true},null,null]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1562752317506 (11:51:57 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time))
[Appium] Appium v1.14.0 creating new WindowsDriver (v1.5.1) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   app: C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
[Appium]   deviceName: WindowsPC
[Appium]   platformName: Windows
[Appium]   newCommandTimeout: 0
[Appium]   connectHardwareKeyboard: true
[BaseDriver] Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {"app":"C:\\Windows\\System...
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
[BaseDriver]   app
[BaseDriver]   connectHardwareKeyboard
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: b4f9003f-6a56-47b8-b9f3-bf70ac3dc91d
[WinAppDriver] You must use WinAppDriver version 1.1
[WinAppDriver] Verifying WinAppDriver version 1.1 is installed via comparing the checksum.
[WinAppDriver] Deleting WinAppDriver session
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1562752317614 (11:51:57 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not verify WinAppDriver install; re-run install
[MJSONWP]     at C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-windows-driver\lib\winappdriver.js:35:13
[MJSONWP]     at Generator.next ()
[MJSONWP]     at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
[MJSONWP]     at _next (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
[MJSONWP]     at run (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:75:22)
[MJSONWP]     at C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:92:30
[MJSONWP]     at flush (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\modules\_microtask.js:18:9)
[MJSONWP]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 113 ms - 190
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {}
[HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session 404 1 ms - 57
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling did not help.
Am i doing anything wrong? Shall windows driver be started manually?

Comment: I am not writing code. I am trying to connect using appium inspector.I would like to do something similar to what shown in this video but for a windows app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ot8cZoUk6o&t=644s
Relevant part being between minute 6 and 10

Answer (score 0):

you can run the selenium server from the windows command prompt like

```
C:\Users\Administrator> “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe” 4723/wd/hub
```

after the server is running. Use breakpoints in your visual studio and then start debugging. When you start debugging, you will see sessionID in your command window. copy that session ID

open appium > File > new session window > custom server > attach to session > paste the session Id > click "attach to session" >

you will get your result. (appium takes some time to grab the current session).